# How do I profit from having a share in an LLC?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, shares, profitability, earnings-per-share

Sorry in advance if I'm asking this question in a wrong place.

For example, if I posses 10% of shares in an LLC in the US that is worth $10 million, what do I profit from? I mean company profits, dividends etc?

Thanks!

Comment: If the company makes a profit and decides to pay a dividend to shareholders then you get 10% of them. Was that what you were asking?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. Is this the only source of income for me then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the US, LLCs do not have shares. LLCs have membership interest. They also have something called "Operating Agreement" which is essentially a contract that governs the relationships between the members (those who have membership interests) and the LLC, and themselves. The OA should spell out how the membership interests are acquired, and what rights they give to their owners, in each area (equity, income, expenses).

For example you may have 10% membership interest that provides you 10% of the equity of the company (net worth), but none of the income or expenses. Or you may buy yourself into an LLC where you'll only be entitled to income, but not equity. Or anything else, the OAs can be whatever the members want them to be, really.

Comment: Thank you for a complete answer! In a situation, where I only have the equity, the only source of money would be to sell my share, right?

Comment: @Dushamishkin if you only have equity then yes, if you want to convert it to cash you'd need to sell it.

Comment: @Dushamishkin, equity usually includes a right to a percent of profits, but as the answer notes, it is possible that it doesn't.  It would be somewhat unusual to have equity without profits.